# .htaccess SEO friendly url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a SEO friendly URL for my home page. For example, I want example.com?url=hello-world to become example.com/hello-world. My current .htaccess has the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It removes .php file extensions correctly, but how can I make it so that it can also generate a SEO friendly url for the home page? The file is index.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On

#remove .php    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#for pretty url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```