# SEO Friendly URI using HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am new in PHP. I have my URL like below

```
http://localhost/index.php?page=20
http://localhost/user.php?id=15&localtion=delhi
http://localhost/folder/profile.php?id=15&active=today
```

What I am looking for convert my URL like below

```
http://localhost/page/20
http://localhost/user/id/15/localtion/delhi
http://localhost/folder/profile/id/15/active/today
```

I am trying from many hours to make it working with .htaccess file but no luck yet

one of little working code is like below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

its removing .php from URL like below

```
http://localhost/index?page=15
```

I have checked many questions and answer in stackoverflow like below

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390397/htaccess-seo-friendly-url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439512/php-url-replace-question-mark-and-parameter-with-slash
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451886/htaccess-for-friendly-url-with-multiple-variables
```

but not able to achieve my goal. Let me know if anyone expert here can help me for doing same and still my php code work fine without any issue.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule for external rewrite.
##Rule to handle from http://localhost/index.php?page=20 to http://localhost/page/20
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?([\w-]+)=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Rule for external rewrite.
##Rule to handle from http://localhost/user.php?id=15&localtion=delhi TO http://localhost/user/id/15/localtion/delhi
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(user)\.php\?([\w-]+)=(\d+)&([\w-]+)=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=301,L]

##Rule for external rewrite.    
##Rule to handle from http://localhost/folder/profile.php?id=15&active=today To http://localhost/folder/profile/id/15/active/today
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(folder)/(profile)\.php\?([\w-]+)=(\d+)&([\w-]+)=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6? [R=301,L]

##internal rewrite rule to handle files internally.    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/$2.php?$3=$4&$6=$6 [QSA,L]

##internal rewrite rule to handle files internally.    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5 [QSA,L]

##internal rewrite rule to handle files internally.    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?$1=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your quick answer. Its giving me error called 403 and my page getting redirected like http://localhost/C:/xamppp/htdocs/page/2?page=20

Comment: @Nidhi, ok sure, I have edited my rules now, pease use latest edited htaccess file and let me know how it goes. Make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: Hi! Again Thanks! Now its not giving error but page redirect like http://localhost/page/2?page=20

Comment: @Nidhi, please do let me know sample URL which you are hitting and what error you are getting?

Comment: I am trying like localhost/index.php?page=20 and getting result like localhost/page/2?page=20

Comment: First one is causing issue, it should 20 but its giving 2 in URL and its still have GET parameter with question mark in all 3 URLS

Comment: @Nidhi, I have updated my rules now, Kindly do check them once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: its still same!

Comment: @Nidhi, please do clear cache before testing this should work IMHO. let me know

Comment: All except First one is working fine. First one is still giving me 2 in URL instead of 20 like http://localhost/page/2

Comment: if I change 20 to 50 like page = 50, then its giving me 5

Comment: @Nidhi, fixed it now, could you please do check now and let me know i have edited it now, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi! Thanks but its still removing last one digit from value like page =200 then its 20, if 2000 then its 200

Comment: @Nidhi, it's purely a cache issue, these rules have worked for me fine. Kindly do clear your cache and then try updated rules, I hope you have changed your htaccess file with updated rules.

Comment: Yeah! its worked. Thanks a lot! can you just explain me what is /%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6? so if I have to make new rule I can make it. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Nidhi, yeah I will add a detailed explanation in few mins or so, and will let you know here

Comment: @Nidhi, Your welcome madam jee. I updated htaccess file with comments now. About your question of `%1`, `%2` etc, so what we do in these rules is we use regex to match patterns in left side of `RewriteCond` and then use them as backreference in right side. You could https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html link will help you to understand the same. Go through them and let me know in case of any queries here.

Comment: I have posted another question, Let me know if you can help me again on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353152/getting-data-fine-in-browser-and-postman-but-in-php-curl-connection-refused Thanks!

Comment: @Nidhi, Hey Nidhi, thanks for letting know but I am that fluent with php :) may be other experts could help you in same, cheers.