# Getting Data fine in Browser, Postman, localhost But in Web Server connection refused

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get data from below URL using PHP and CURL

http://121.58.193.173:8080/rainfall/map_list.do?ymdhm=202105012030&basin=&_=1619601119620

Its working fine in browser and I am getting json response.

Now I have monitored network and tried to make request using postman

with below header its working fine in Postman as GET request

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Host:121.58.193.173:8080
```

I am getting response in Postman and its working fine, Now I am trying to use it in my PHP file with curl like below which is generated by POSTMAN

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://121.58.193.173:8080/rainfall/map_list.do?ymdhm=202105012030&basin=&_=1619601119620',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0',
    'Accept:  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language:  en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate',
    'Connection:  keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:  1',
    'Cache-Control:  max-age=0',
    'Host: 121.58.193.173:8080'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

Above PHP file working fine in localhost but in Web Server Its not providing response and getting connection refused error. Now I have monitored network for my PHP file and found all same information except host, When I request direct URL in browser, its SET host as  121.58.193.173:8080 but in my request, its set MY domain name as host like example.com and may be that reason its refusing connection, I have manually set host in curl, but its not making any difference in it.

Let me know if anyone here can help me for solve the puzzle for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I am the same guy from freelancer, Use file_get_contents function it will work fine

Comment: BlackXero , Have you found it working? file_get_contents have also same issue

Comment: I've read your issue in freelancer. I've tested it locally and on an online server and it totally works. I've also changed the host header and all requests were successful.

It should be useful to look at the logs on the API side, to see if there's any difference between the requests made by my server and yours.

I'll make another set of requests, with a custom "freelancer.com" User-Agent, so you could check it out

Comment: @TadeoArmenta, You are in freelancer? give me username so we can chat there

Comment: Did you check request limits in API Documentation?

Comment: I'm sorry @Hidhi, yesterday was mother's day where I live, so I was offline with family.
Hope you have resolved your issue

Comment: Hi, what you showed is working fine, how can you reproduce the error you are writing about?

Answer (score -1):

it's not php issue

maybe firewall on your server blocking outbound connection

Comment: My Server does not blocking outbound connection, I have tested it with other URL and its working fine!

Answer (score -1):

````
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://121.58.193.173:8080/rainfall/map_list.do?ymdhm=202105012030&basin=&_=1619601119620",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-SANDBOXDEMOKEY-X"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
$resp = json_decode($response, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($resp);
echo "</pre>";```

here is a result on my server: [Result on my End][1]


  [1]: https://mony.com.ng/index.php
````